# Angular13: Mat-Select displays wrong value when values are saved in array

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular13, mat-select

I have a dynamic section of rows of mat-selections. How it works: Whenever I select a value in the current last row a new row with a mat-select should appear and whenever I deselect a value that row should disappear from the shown rows. To achieve this I save all selected values (in relation to their row) in an array called *rows*. New rows with no value are saved with *null* in *rows*.
Here is the corresponding code:

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field class="input regular" appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>{{options[0].viewValue}}</mat-label>
        <mat-select (selectionChange)="onMainChange($event.value, i)" [value]="row">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value >= 0 ? option.value : null">
                {{option.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

TS:

```
options : SelectionComponent[] = [
    {value: -1, viewValue: "Choose an Option"},
    {value: 0, viewValue: "Option1"},
    {value: 1, viewValue: "Option2"},
    {value: 2, viewValue: "Option3"},
    {value: 3, viewValue: "Option4"},
    {value: 4, viewValue: "Option5"},
    {value: 5, viewValue: "Option6"},
    {value: 6, viewValue: "Option7"},
    {value: 7, viewValue: "Option8"},
]

rows : (number | null)[] = []

constructor(private cd : ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rows = [null]
}


onMainChange(value : number | null, rIdx : number) {
    if(value == null) {
        this.rows.splice(rIdx, 1)
    } else {
        this.rows[rIdx] = value
    }
    
    //Check to add row
    if(this.rows.length < this.options.length - 1 && this.rows[this.rows.length - 1] != null) {
      this.rows.push(null)
    }
}
```

Now, when I select a value (e.g. Option1) in the first row, *rows* updates to *[0, null]* which is corret, but the visuals update to:
[image: Wrong display.] 
which is wrong. It should update to:
 [image: Correct display.]

Does anybody know where the error is or have an idea how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mind to create stackblitz and add link here? with reproducible problem statement, thanks :)

Comment: For the Statement: "When selecting an option in the last row a new row with the same selected value appears, which is incorrect.". The link to StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-13-starter-x1xj4z-mlzy7q?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Really strange, I also trying to see, what's going wrong. But no luck yet. I will update you if I find anything. Thanks :)

Comment: That would be great, thanks for your help!